# How to defer mails which were hard-bounced by an upstream MTA

Tags: postfix

Our upstream MTA is being temporarily disabled but responds with "550 contact support". This means all our automatically generated emails are going down the drain.

How do I configure Postfix so that the hard bounce is ignored and the mails deferred?

`soft_bounce = "yes"` does not help, because it only affects my own responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing a few things.

When an upstream SMTP server sends you a 550 response, that means the upstream server is **rejecting** your mail; it is not "being bounced".

*Your* server would be the one generating the bounce message in response to that 550.

`soft_bounce = yes` does in fact directly influence the above, and setting it means that your server reacts to every 5xx response with a defer action for later retry (up to the configured limit).

From the documentation:

> soft_bounce (default: no)
>   Safety net to keep mail queued that would
>   otherwise be returned to the sender. This parameter disables
>   locally-generated bounces, and prevents the Postfix SMTP server from
>   rejecting mail permanently, by changing 5xx reply codes into 4xx.

If you think this is not happening, include some logs that show this.